# Git failing to ignore .DS_Store defined in global ignore

Tags: git, operating-system

I'm fairly new to git and hope I'm not doing something terribly silly. I've been living without a way of ignoring files in Git and have finally had my fill of accidentally adding OS files to my repositories.

I have a new git repository the `git status` of which is:

```
# On branch master
#
# Initial commit
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   .DS_Store
#   README.markdown
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Running `git add .` followed by `git status` produces:

```
# On branch master
#
# Initial commit
#
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   new file:   .DS_Store
#   new file:   README.markdown
#
```

Running `git config -l` shows:

```
core.excludesfile=/Users/Chris/.gitignore
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.ignorecase=true
```

The contents of `/Users/Chris/.gitignore` are:

```
# Compiled source #
###################
*.com
*.class
*.dll
*.exe
*.o
*.so

# Packages #
############
# it's better to unpack these files and commit the raw source
# git has its own built in compression methods
*.7z
*.dmg
*.gz
*.iso
*.jar
*.rar
*.tar
*.zip

# Logs and databases #
######################
*.log
*.sql
*.sqlite

# OS generated files #
######################
.DS_Store?
ehthumbs.db
Icon?
Thumbs.db
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try removing question mark after `.DS_Store` in your global `.gitignore`?

Comment: Thanks very much! That works fine. My only question is why was the question mark there in the first place? It's a default ignore file that came with git. I assumed the ? was part of the syntax.

Comment: I have no idea ;-) Question mark means any character, so it would probably cover stuff like .DS_Store1, .DS_Store2, etc.

Comment: That would make sense so the question mark means a character is required and therefore would not match .DS_Store - very strange.

Comment: @Aaron, Assuming there's more than `.DS_Store` to it. Not that it means anything, but I haven't seen these.

Comment: Me neither. But it's used in github's .gitignore_global example. See http://help.github.com/ignore-files/

Comment: Well, it is sure better than `.DS_Store?` ;-)